# Correct syntax for JS Test Driver "assertException"?

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use JS Test Driver's assertException method. From google's documentation it should be: assertException([msg], callback, error). However, no matter what I do, I always get an [ERROR] for this test (instead of a [PASS] since there was an exception):

```
ComponentTest.prototype.testEnforceUniqueComponentIds = function() {
    assertException(function(){
        this.component = new myNamespace.component(this.testComponentSettings);
    });
}
```

And in my src JS:

```
myNamespace.component = function(params){
if (typeof params.selector == 'undefined'){
    throw new Error('no selector provided');
}
this.settings = jQuery.extend({}, {
    id              : 'defaultComponentId',
    type            : 'defaultComponentType',
    selector    : 'body',
    isUnique    : false
}, params);

if(typeof(myNamespace.componentRegistry[params.id]) === "undefined"){
    myNamespace.registerComponent(this);
} else {
    throw new Error('non-unique component id provided');
}
}
```

Here is the output from js-test-driver:

```
C:\xampp2\htdocs\myNamespace\v2>java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --tests all --verbose
[PASSED] ComponentTest.testInit
  [LOG] setUp
  [LOG] tearDown
[PASSED] ComponentTest.testDestroy
  [LOG] setUp
  [LOG] tearDown
[ERROR] ComponentTest.testEnforceUniqueComponentIds
  [LOG] setUp
Total 3 tests (Passed: 2; Fails: 0; Errors: 1) (1.00 ms)
  Firefox 7.0.1: Run 3 tests (Passed: 2; Fails: 0; Errors 1) (1.00 ms)
    ComponentTest.testEnforceUniqueComponentIds error (1.00 ms):
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to have the code within the assertException callback actually throw an exception without it causing an ERROR in the test - isn't this what is supposed to happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
assertException(function(){
    this.component = new myNamespace.component(this.testComponentSettings);
}, "Error");
```

error argument should be Error.name of thrown error(such as "ReferenceError", "TypeError", etc.).